# Convert "AES-128-ECB" encryption code from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, encryption, aes

I have a requirement where I need to convert some PHP code to C#.. following is the PHP Code that needs to be converted:

```
$data = "Hello World!";

$key = "RTc0MDkwMEEwMDYxQjc4Mg=="

$encRaw = openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-128-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
```

To convert this openssl encryption, I am using below C# code:

```
    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        byte[] encrypted;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            //aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;
    }
```

But somehow this is not giving me same result that PHP function is returning.

Can someone please help me to identify the issue in my code? Or suggest me what other changes should I do in my code so that I get the similar result that PHP function is returning.

Comment: It would be a good idea to set the [`Mode` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode?view=net-6.0); the `Aes` class defaults to CBC, not ECB.

Comment: In the PHP code, key size (192 bits) and AES-128 variant do not match (which results in an implicit truncation of the key). Shorten the key in the C# code accordingly. Or alternatively, Base64 decode the key in both codes (which gives a 128 bits key).